# Send a confirmation email using php

Tags: php

I am using the script below to return an email with the submitted fields to my email address.

I have recently found the need to have a confirmation email sent to who ever submitted the form in the first place but am unsure on how to alter the script. I basically need it to say something like "Dear $name, Thanks for contacting us....".

Please can someone help?

```
<?php
//--------------------------Set these paramaters--------------------------

// Subject of email sent to you.
$subject = 'Website Enquiry';

// Your email address. This is where the form information will be sent.
$emailadd = 'myemail@myemail.co.uk';

// Where to redirect after form is processed.
$url = 'thanks.php';

// Makes all fields required. If set to '1' no field can not be empty. If set to '0' any or all fields can be empty.
$req = '0';

// --------------------------Do not edit below this line--------------------------
$text = "WEBSITE ENQUIRY:\n\n";
$space = ' ';
$line = '
';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
if ($req == '1')
{
if ($value == '')
{echo "$key is empty";die;}
}
$j = strlen($key);
if ($j >= 20)
{echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";die;}
$j = 20 - $j;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++)
{$space .= ' ';}
$value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
$conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
$text .= $conc;
$space = ' ';
}
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$emailadd.'');
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

The script allows for any form element to be sent in the email without the need of including it within the php script.

The email address is collected in the html

```
<span class="input">
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email"/>
  </span>
```

and the name...

```
<span class="input">
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
 </span>
```

Many thanks

Craig

Comment: Your script is simply sending the form back to the user as is, unless you haven't included the parts where it sends the form data to you

Comment: That's correct - i'm not great with php - so i can't work out how to do the rest. I'm looking for help if possible.

Comment: FYI: Most of that script just validates & formats the input.  The actual email is sent at the bottom.  You should get acquainted with the PHP mail function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @Marc B: Isn't the script sending the form data to the website owner?

Comment: @Alex: the `mail()` is using `$emailAdd` for both the To: and From: fields, and that var's coming from the posted form.

Comment: @Marc B: No, it isn't; `$emailAdd` is preset in the script. Look at lines 7/8.

Comment: @Alex argh you're right. Remind me to rub my eyes with a wire brush later today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will send a confirmation to the user who submitted the form, but it doesn't check to make sure they've entered a valid email address. There's a handy script at [isemail.info](http://isemail.info/) which will validate that for you.

Insert the code just above the `---Do not edit below this line---` line.

```
// Subject of confirmation email.
$conf_subject = 'Your recent enquiry';

// Who should the confirmation email be from?
$conf_sender = 'Organisation Name <no-reply@myemail.co.uk>';

$msg = $_POST['Name'] . ",\n\nThank you for your recent enquiry. A member of our 
team will respond to your message as soon as possible.";

mail( $_POST['Email'], $conf_subject, $msg, 'From: ' . $conf_sender );
```